# Find the function behind this data series

Tags: functions, logarithms, curves

I try to discover the formula behind a video game system. My goal is to create a tool that will help players. The bonus granted by this system follows a logarithmic curve whose values ​​are integers :

$0,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,...$

$Floor(log(X)10)$, where $X$ is the index of the value in the series, gives good results without being perfect either :

$0,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,...$

Here are the differences highlighted ( index - expected result - result before floor ) :

- 5 - 7 - 6.989
- 6 - 8 - 7.781
- 16 - 11 - 12.041
- 20 - 12 - 13.01
- 49 - 17 - 16.901
- 50 - 17 - 16.989

What can I change to correct these differences?

Comment: Wolframalpha has a curve fitting tool; I quickly plopped your values up to 16 into it and the (least squares) result was $4.31485 \log(0.868621 x)$ for the natural logarithm. That seems quite arbitrary, however, so I'm guessing there's a simpler way to construct the same sequence - perhaps it used another base for the logarithm.

Comment: Perhaps the sequence is completely arbitrary? Someone just thought up some numbers and put them next to each other?

Comment: @user10186512, I came to the same conclusion but could not determine it. I lack mathematical skills for that.

Comment: @MattiP., the game is entirely designed to have no hard limits. Everything works with formulas. It would be surprising that this is not the case for that.